# how to parse a json file in in c#, where attributes are not specific

Tags: c#, json

Following is a sample json file. I want to parse ""dishIdToMealId" in a key value pair list.

```
{
  "timeline": {
    "dateToDayId": {
      "2016-08-17": 359903
    },
    "dishIdToMealId": {
      "1523943": 587408,
      "1523953": 587408,
      "1524217": 587509
    },
    "mealIdToDayId": {
      "587408": 359903,
      "587509": 359903
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: And are you trying to deserialize this to a type you've already declared? Have you tried declaring a field of type `Dictionary<string, int>` for `dishToMealId` for example?

Comment: What library are you using Newtonsoft?